# Downtime experienced swapping instances of different sizes

Tags: azure

In production I am running 3 **small** instances of my web role. In staging I have 3 **extra small** instances of that web role. When I swapped them out my site experienced about 2 minutes of downtime which I wasn't expecting.

According to the article [Update, Upgrade and VIP-Swap for Windows Azure Service–What are the Differences?](http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/06/update-upgrade-and-vip-swap-for-windows-azure-servicewhat-are-the-differences.html) this shouldn't have occurred. Why would downtime be experienced during the swap and is there a way to swap roles of different instance sizes without experiencing downtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what Michael has mentioned - there shouldn't have been any downtime.  However, if you're swapping into xtra-small instances that are "cold" and just have been deployed into, IIS will need to recompile the sites and bring them online. Xtra-small instances are notoriously slow.

Thus: Your downtime could have been caused by the compilation/caching/app-start/etc.

Comment: Thanks lgorek. Yesterday, before I swapped in again, I hit the web role in staging. Sure enough I didn't incur any downtime during the swapping process.

Answer (score 3):

While you can change the VM sizes now as part of an in-place update, you should expect some instance downtime.  The Windows Azure fabric controller will walk the upgrade domains, taking 1 upgrade domain down to change the VM sizes, and then moving on to the next.  If you have 2 instances, you shouldn't have noticed an entire outage (just 1 machine going down at a time).

You can see some further details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx.

Comment: Terfdaq's post mentions 3 instances are running.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed that. My apologies.